# Extract value after patern via grep regex

Tags: regex, shell, grep

i'm trying to retrieve a value from a string using grep via a regex expression, the thing is how do i get a value AFTER a expression is found. Like in this example:

```
tcp6   0    0   :::80   :::*     LISTEN     811/apache2
```

i could get the value 80 simply doing "[0-9]{2,}",the problem is that i also match the PID of the process "811", how do i get only the numbers after ":::"  ?

Comment: Why use grep for this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming GNU grep:

```
$ s="tcp6   0    0   :::80   :::*     LISTEN     811/apache2"
$ grep -oP ':::\K\d+' <<<"$s"
80
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk`s may help you here.

***Solution 1st:*** Simplest one change field delimiters to `:::` and space and see the magic.

```
awk -F':::| +' '{print $5}' Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** With use of `sub` in only 4th column.

```
awk '{sub(/:+/,"",$4);print $4}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 3rd:*** using `match` function of `awk` to match a regex of 3 colons and digits in line.

```
awk 'match($0,/:::[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3)}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 4th:*** using multiple `sub`s in complete line to get the expected output.

```
awk '{sub(/[^:]*/,"");sub(/:::/,"");sub(/ +.*/,"");print}'  Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** In case you are using a command by which you are getting shown output then in spite of using `awk.... Input_file` use eg--> `your_command | awk...` for all above codes too.